# How to create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame based on a column in another DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*I am new to Python and Pandas
I need to do the following
I have 2 DataFrames, lets call them df1 and df2

df1

```
Index    Req ID  City_Atlanta   City_Seattle    City_Boston Result  
 0        X         1                0            0           0  
 1        Y         0                1            0           0  
 2        Z         0                0            1           1
```

df2

```
Index    Req_ID    City        
  0         X      Atlanta     
  1         Y      Seattle     
  2         Z      Boston
```

I want  to add a column in df2 called result such that df2.result = False if df1.result = 0 and df2.result = True if df1.result = 1

The final result should look like
df2

```
Index    Req_ID    City       result 
  0         X      Atlanta     False
  1         Y      Seattle     False
  2         Z      Boston      True
```

I am new to asking question on Stack Overflow as well so pardon any common mistakes.

Comment: based on what? what is the common key between the 2 dataframes? can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Index or Req_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they're the same lengths you can do:

```
df2['Result'] = df1['Result']==1
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering `Req ID` is the matching key and the length of the dfs are not the same, you can use:

```
df2['Result'] = df2.Req_ID.map(dict(zip(df['Req ID'],df.Result))).astype(bool)

0    False
1    False
2     True
```

If lengths are equal you can use the above sol by @aws_apprentice

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply` a `bool` to the 0,1's.

```
df2['Result'] = df1['Result'].apply(bool)
```

You can also `map` a dictionary of values.

```
df2['Result'] = df1['Result'].map({0: False, 1: True})
```

Comment: that is true, OP hasn't specified anything yet

Comment: change apply to astype

Comment: that’s another possible solution sure